# Email Services + How to handle undelivered or bounce emails

Tags: apex-email-service

This might be a known issue. But i could not find enough info to resolve the issue. We are using Email Service's email address as a From address to send emails to consumers. If consumer's email address is wrong, then the undelivered message is getting attached to the case as the subject line has the case's reference id. How can i prevent these email messages from attaching to cases.

Thanks
Ashok.